# How do I resolve UnsatisfiedLinkError with JavaCPP native libraries while using JPMS Java modules?

Tags: java, gradle, java-platform-module-system, module-info, javacpp

I have a Java 17 project using Gradle with a multitude of JavaCPP libraries. I started with a [simple demo project](https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/tree/master/samples/javacv-demo) that I cloned from the JavaCPP Github repo. This sample project incorporates several native libs such as OpenCV, ffmpeg, etc., so I thought it'd be a good test. And, no surprise, it worked just fine. It brought up my camera, did the face detection, etc. All very cool.

My aim - **I want to modularize my JavaCPP projects to be JPMS compliant.**

Not easy. So, to troubleshoot, I figure that I would start with good test code, which is why I'm working with the official JavaCPP Gradle demo program.

So, I did the following to convert it to be JPMS compliant:

1. Created a `module-info.java` placed down `src/main/java`. I added the appropriate `requires` statements (see below).
2. Modified `build.gradle` to add several `*-platform` dependencies and a few other plugins, including JavaFX.

The TL;DR - I got it to work (though the camera appears at an angle in the app window, which is just weird, but I'm assuming I'm still missing a library in `module-info.java`). The problem is that it only worked after I not only specified numerous additional `*-platform` dependencies in `build.gradle`, but also needed to list the actual native platform libraries in `module-info.java`. So, for instance, I need to add the following statement:

`requires org.bytedeco.opencv.macosx.x86_64;`

If I do not do that, then I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path: /Users/brk009/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.

My main question - **How can I make a modular JavaCPP project build and execute properly *without* hard coding the platform dependent native libraries in `module-info.java`?** I thought that just specifying the `*-platform` libraries in `module-info.java` would do it, but nope.

If this was just a project for my own system, then fine - I'd live with it. However, I want to pass some of my example code off to my students. It'd be fine if they all ran Macs. However, my students have quite a heterogeneous platform base (i.e. a mix of Mac, Windows, and Linux users.) Ideally, it'd be great to have a platform-independent codebase and let my program build and run regardless of the platform. Heck, I'd even be happy if I only needed to specify the platform as a parameter for `gradlew` as a command-line argument, such as indicated [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin), where I could just specify `-PjavacppPlatform=linux-x86_64`. But that did not work either.

I did verify that `Loader.Detector.getPlatform()` returns the correct platform string, and `Loader.getCacheDir()` returns ~/.javacpp/cache as you would expect.

Any help/guidance would be immensely appreciated! Thank you kindly.

---

**module-info.java**

```
module HelloJavaCPP {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.bytedeco.javacpp;
    requires org.bytedeco.javacpp.macosx.x86_64;  // I do NOT WANT to hard code any platform!
    requires org.bytedeco.javacv;
    requires org.bytedeco.opencv;
    requires org.bytedeco.opencv.macosx.x86_64;
    requires org.bytedeco.ffmpeg;
    requires org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.macosx.x86_64;
    requires org.bytedeco.openblas;
    requires org.bytedeco.openblas.macosx.x86_64;
}
```

---

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.12'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.10'
    id 'org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-platform' version '1.5.7'
}

group = 'org.hello'
version = '1.5.7'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}

javafx {
    version = "17.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.graphics','javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

dependencies {
    api "org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.5.7"
    api 'org.bytedeco:opencv-platform:4.5.5-1.5.7'
//    api "org.bytedeco:opencv-platform-gpu:4.5.5-$version"
    api "org.bytedeco:ffmpeg-platform-gpl:5.0-$version"
    api 'org.bytedeco:openblas-platform:0.3.19-1.5.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

application {
    mainModule = "$moduleName"
    mainClass = "org.hello.Demo"
}
```

---

**settings.gradle**
I'm including this just incase.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'HelloJavaCPP'

gradle.rootProject { ext.javacppVersion = '1.5.7' }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're missing? Javacpp's presets already comes with module-info.java in there. They're generated automatically.

Comment: I want to achieve two things: 1) run my test app above as a modular project (meaning, it has its own module-info.java file), and 2) NOT have to specify the actual platform system architecture with the native libraries that need to be linked.

Comment: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/JavaCPP-and-JPMS-%28Java-Platform-Module-System%29 says:
"All native modules required by an application must then be added to the module graph, either using the application module descriptor, or using an --add-modules launch option." So, that seems to suggest I *need* those system architecture specific `requires` statements?

Comment: The module system makes this really hard to achieve, and the plugins for JavaFX have known issues that make them unusable at the moment, see https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/1435, https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/1754, and https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/JavaFX-and-JavaCPP

Comment: Thanks Sam - that last page about JavaFX and JavaCPP helped me find a solution!!! I'll post my fix for `gradle.build` and `module-info.java` as an answer. That clarified things quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Those links posted by Samuel above were immensely helpful. It turns out there are some modularity peculiarities with JavaFX that can wreck havoc when using JavaFX with non-JavaFX modules such as those in JavaCPP. See [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/JavaFX-and-JavaCPP).

The key part that was important:

> We can either use the run goal of the JavaFX Maven plugin, the java goal of the Exec Maven plugin, or manually launch java with a module path computed from Maven dependencies and option `--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH`.

Once I figured out how to add a JVM argument in Gradle, I was able to remove all hard-coded architecture `requires` statements, *and* I can now use `gradlew run`, let JavaCPP's `Loader` class do all the work of discovering the architecture itself and loading the appropriate native libraries!

The two most important files that need to change:

---

**module-info.java**

Notice how much simpler this becomes, and it has NO hard-coded platform system architecture information, which is exactly what we want:

```
module HelloJavaCPP {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.bytedeco.javacpp;
    requires org.bytedeco.javacv;
    requires org.bytedeco.opencv;
    requires org.bytedeco.ffmpeg;
    requires org.bytedeco.openblas;
}
```

---

**build.gradle**

The most important change I needed to make (which I got from information posted [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/JavaFX-and-JavaCPP) was to add a `run` configuration, and specify the JVM argument `--add-modules

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.12'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.10'
    id 'org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-platform' version "$javacppVersion"
}

group = 'org.hello'
version = '1.5.7'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    // javacppPlatform - should be autodetected, but can also specify on cmd line
    // as -PjavacppPlatform=macosx-x86_64
//    javacppPlatform = 'linux-x86_64,macosx-x86_64,windows-x86_64,etc' // defaults to Loader.getPlatform()
    javacppPlatform = 'macosx-x86_64' // defaults to Loader.getPlatform()
}

javafx {
    version = "17.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.graphics','javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

dependencies {
    api "org.bytedeco:javacpp-platform:$javacppVersion"
    api "org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:$javacppVersion"
    api "org.bytedeco:opencv-platform:4.5.5-1.5.7"
    api "org.bytedeco:ffmpeg-platform-gpl:5.0-1.5.7"
    api "org.bytedeco:openblas-platform:0.3.19-1.5.7"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

application {
    mainModule = "$moduleName"
    mainClass = "org.hello.Demo"
}

// THIS WAS THE PRIMARY CHANGE: 
run {
    jvmArgs = ['--add-modules', 'ALL-MODULE-PATH']
}
```

It's worth noting that I was able to remove the `ext` configuration in `build.gradle`, which allows `Loader.getPlatform()` to do the work of determining the platform at runtime, and it worked just fine! (I left it in place just for reference purposes.)

I hope this helps others. I did NOT test out building an image, as judging from what I read, that is quite an additional level of complexity. We'll tackle that another time.

Thank you again.